# How do I create a batch file that supports an older version of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, visual-studio-2008

I have been building Smart Device application on Visual Studio 2008 and have been using a batch file to do so.

This has been working until I have installed Visual Studio 2015 and I wanted to still build and debug the solution via Visual Studio 2008 because Visual Studio 2015 doesn't support Smart Device development. However, using the same batch file I can no longer do so.

I am looking for a way to be able to target the devenv of the older version of Visual Studio for the batch file without uninstalling Visual Studio 2015, because I too have projects built on that version.

NOTE: I can run Visual Studio 2008 perfectly fine and using their on-click build tool it builds fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch file is probably picking up environment variables (INCLUDE, LIB etc) set up by VS 2015, which the 2008 toolset will not work with.

The `Visual Studio 2008` menu should have a `Visual Studio Tools` submenu. Run `Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt` from that submenu, which will open a `cmd` console with the VS 2008 environment set correctly. Run your batch file at that prompt.

You can automate it by writing a small batch file to first execute `vcvarsall.bat` (which is what the menu command does), then run your batch.

```
@call "<path-to-vs2008-install-directory>\vcvarsall.bat" x86
@call "<your-batch.bat>"
```